# AliExpress запрос к API на php

Tags: php

Пытаюсь сделать запрос к [api aliexpress](https://portals.aliexpress.com/help/help_center_API.html) метод `generatePromotionLinks` что вставлять в параметр `urls` как организовать параметр `_aop_signature`: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Там есть демо но на `java` а мне нужна на `php` вот [здесь](http://open.china.alibaba.com/api/sys_signature.htm?spm=a260s.8208020.0.0.3dbd6485kHAZXT&ns=cn.alibaba.open#apiRule) написано как организовать `_aop_signature` но я все равно не понял, ребята если кто то разбирается помогите пожалуйста, 3 день юзаю интернет но нечего на `php` не нашел